# deleteing list items from SharePoint list, shows 'no title' for newly added items

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

We have a list with over 5000 items, which is causing issue with the SharePoint list. We deleted old items and that fixed the issue that we were having with the InfoPath form. However, when we add a new items we get "No title" instead of unique ID as shown below:
[image]

So, how we fix it so that we get then next id instead of "No Title"

Here are the ID field in InfoPath form:

[image]

Comment: How are you creating the UniqueID? Calculated field or Workflow?

Comment: I don't know as I was not the one was created the InfoPath form. It is not a workflow for sure.

Comment: You can first check the column settings and find out if it is a calculated column or not.

Comment: Checked the list settings and the scorecard ID is a Single lines of text

Answer (score 0):

You may need to drill further into the default value of "Scorecard ID" (in InfoPath) to see what it's doing.  From your screenshot, it's currently set to Value = "ID".  If that "ID" value is from the "Main Data Connection", then that right there is the problem, as a new form wouldn't actually have an ID value until after being submitted to the SharePoint list and having a corresponding item created.  You can verify this if the "Scorecard ID" field is visible in your form by opening one of these *No Title* items, as you would see the correct value showing up within the form (which if you then saved the form again, would submit properly to the list).

Assuming the above is what's happening, the fix is to create a submit rule that either finds the next ID in sequence and updates the "Scorecard ID" field to that value before the form is submitted to SharePoint, or to submit it to SharePoint twice, once to populate the ID field, then a second time to force the "Scorecard ID" field to use the now existing ID value.